# Spring framework request entity: what is T for a GET request?

Tags: java, spring

I am using the Spring framework to query an GET endpoint, creating the request as follows:

```
String url = ...
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
RequestEntity<?> requestEntity = RequestEntity.get(url).headers(httpHeaders).build();
```

Now obviously the compiler rejects the "?" as a type, and according to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/RequestEntity.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-), the type specified here should be the type of the body.

But this is a GET request. There is no body. How do I use this function? (Removing the <?> altogether does not work either).

Edit: Fixed my example, which, as correctly pointed out by @Nico Van Belle, was missing the .build()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the Void type. Normally, IDEs should be smart enough to add it via autocomplete.

```java
RequestEntity<Void> build = RequestEntity.get(url).headers(httpHeaders).build();
```

Do note that your example does not return a RequestEntity, but a builder. You still have to call `build()` from the builder to actually build the RequestEntity object.